# Difference between Linux-PAM + SSSD and Linux-PAM using NSCD

Tags: pam, sssd

Confused when it comes to Linux PAM, but also when people are talking about PAM + sssd.
I know `sssd` is some sort of a cache of users and groups, while PAM is used for authentication of local users. The same goes for `nscd` which is also some sort of cache, but what's the difference between that and `sssd`?

This confusion lead me to another matter, what's the difference between PAM + SSSD and LDAP + SSSD? Are ldap and pam in this case "mutual exlusive"?

Comment: `sssd` is not some kind of cache, although it does employ it. Just check the wikipedia entry for it for a concise description. And in case you still don't get it, sssd, can use ldap as well as a few others and handle them for authentication for a variety of clients such as sudo, ssh, autofs all through pam. It's a one-stop-shop.

Answer (score 2):

Linux PAM (Pluggable Authentication Modules) is a framework used to authenticate users in Linux-based systems. It provides a flexible and modular approach to authentication, allowing system administrators to configure various authentication schemes and policies.

SSSD (System Security Services Daemon) is a service that provides a caching mechanism for identity and authentication information, including users, groups, and their respective attributes. SSSD can be configured to retrieve this information from various identity providers, including local files, LDAP directories, and Active Directory domains.

NSCD (Name Service Cache Daemon) is another service that provides caching for name resolution information, such as hostnames, IP addresses, and network services. It can be used to reduce the load on the system's name resolution infrastructure by caching frequently accessed information.

The main difference between SSSD and NSCD is that SSSD is focused on caching identity and authentication information, while NSCD is focused on caching name resolution information. Additionally, SSSD is designed to work with various identity providers, including local files and LDAP directories, while NSCD is more limited in its functionality.

When it comes to PAM and SSSD, the two are not mutually exclusive. In fact, they can be used together to provide a more comprehensive authentication solution. PAM provides the authentication framework, while SSSD provides the caching and retrieval of identity and authentication information.

LDAP (Lightweight Directory Access Protocol) is a protocol used to access and manage directory services, which store and organize information about network resources, such as users, groups, and computers. When used with SSSD, LDAP can serve as an identity provider for user and group information. In this case, PAM and SSSD are used to authenticate users, while LDAP is used to retrieve identity and authorization information.

In summary, PAM and SSSD are complementary technologies that can be used together to provide a more comprehensive authentication solution. LDAP can be used as an identity provider in conjunction with SSSD to retrieve user and group information. NSCD is a separate service that provides caching for name resolution information.